# List which ports my Java application is using

Tags: java, sockets, javafx-2, port

I am developing a simple Java video streaming application using JavaFX. I can't use other libraries (vlcj) because of licensing.
Anyway, my player works pretty fine, but I need to know on which local port it establishes connection. Since it seems that JavaFX doesn't offer such possibility, I am wondering if there is a way to catch/list all the Java opened connections/sockets.

Code follows,
thanks in advance.

```
String mediaURL = "somepath";
Group root = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
Media media = new Media(mediaURL);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
mediaView.setCache(false);
root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier.html

Comment: Which operating system do your use?

Comment: @AurA that link is about physical com port

Comment: @ericson it must run on win/linux/mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On linux/mac, open a terminal and:

1. use `jps` command to find the `pid` of your java process
2. use `lsof -p <pid> |grep ESTABLISHED` to list the established connections.

For windows you can check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows).

Comment: Although it isn't exactly what I had in mind, I had to use this kind of approach.